# Update huge table by values from text file condition

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have 45 million Innodb database which I need to Update with condition from text file containing 1.5 million rows.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `value` = 1
    WHERE `column` = '_HERE DATA FROM TEXT FILE_
```

with 1.5 million condition values';

How to achieve this? Maybe, I need to import 1.5 values into other table and do like this? Seems like temporary table in this query will be too big or query too long.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `value` = 1
    WHERE `column` IN (SELECT `column` FROM `table2`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change more than a few hundred rows in a single `UPDATE`, you need to rethink the schema.  Such as putting `value` in a single place in another table.  And then do a `JOIN` to get the current value of `value`.

Can you provide specific information, such as the semantics of "value" and what the "table" contains -- log info, purchase orders, genealogy, personnel, whatever.  This will help us provide you more tailored answers.

Meanwhile, as a general rule, avoid this construct: `IN ( SELECT ... )`

Comment: `Table` contains md5 hash values, and status. I need to update status =1 where md5 hash value = given 1.5 million values. Table contains 50 other columns. Table contains info about country organisations.

Comment: What does "status" mean?  What percentage of the 1.5 entries already have "1"?  What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table?  Did the list of 1.5 come from a CSV file?  (I ask the random-seeming questions because there are different optimizations based on your answers.)

Comment: Status means nothing. I have few statuses for internal usage. Currently in 45mil table all statuses are same, I need to make `UPDATE STATUS = 1 WHERE MD5 = _each row in txt input_` No keys in table yet (except ID column), its just projected website. 1.5 mil values comes from txt file.

Comment: @wtfowned - Is "status=1" _changing_ all rows?  Or is it leaving them all alone (because all were 1 already)?

Comment: Leaving them alone. Actually, I can't understand why you need such information, could you please explain? I can't explain the thing to you which I couldn't explain for myself. I think I've explained the whole task in start post. Need update column2 where column1. Only this. But conditions are 1.5 mil rows for column1. Thats all, nothing else to explain.

Comment: @wtfowned - SQL performance is quite involved.  Touching 1.5M rows takes a lot of time.  If the operation also requires touching all 45M rows (due to lack of index, that makes things perhaps 30 times as slow.  `UPDATEing` each row -- if nothing changed, the effort is considerably less, but it took some effort to realize that nothing is changing.

Comment: @wtfowned - And...  I am wondering if _first_ devising a `SELECT` to discover those that need changing, _then_ using that result (via `JOIN` in the `UPDATE`) would be the fastest way.  Still that would involve (at least) reading the entire 1.5, then randomly looking up 1.5M (of the 45M), etc.